# Text looks odd on certain places in google chrome after upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, fonts

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 from 17.10 and suddenly the font rendering on google chrome looks very strange. There appear to be additional marks on it. I attempted to restore all chrome settings to default, but it did not appear to fix the issue.

[image]

Any thoughts on how to resolve? The issue is not present on any other applications on my system, so it appears to be a chrome specific issue.

Comment: Do you have the proper drivers for your video card?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this with version 54 of Chrome. Upgrading to 67 sorted it out